# How to change redirect code?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, login

How to change the function: `woocommerce_myaccount_page_id` code below:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink( get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id') ); ?> ">
```

To redirect it to WordPress login screen instead of "My account" page.

```
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink( get_option( 'WHAT CODE ENTER HERE TO REDIRECT TO PAGE WP-LOGIN.PHP?') ); ?> ">
```

Comment: just write `echo wp_login_url();` in href value.

Comment: It did not work, I put it like this: <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( get_option('echo wp_login_url(); in href value') ); ?> ">

That's right?

Comment: See the answer below!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`wp_login_url`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_url).

```
<a href="<?php echo wp_login_url(); ?> ">login</a>
```

To redirect to home page *after* login, add the `$redirect` argument and point to `home_url()`

```
<a href="<?php echo wp_login_url( home_url() ); ?> ">login</a>
```

Comment: Tanks. Is solved!

Comment: @RenatoKeüller Pls accept the answer if it helped you :) (check mark to the left of the answer)